# Lambda Expression to search with conditions and return only 1 latest result

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a List that contains `Supplier` data and I would like to search it by using `SupplierID`, non-active supplier and only 1 latest result.

So I've got:

```
List<Supplier> filteredList = this.toList();    
filteredList.OrderByDescending(m => m.ModifiedDatetime).FirstOrDefault();    
filteredList.Where(f => (f.Active == false && f.FieldId == SupplierFieldID))
            .ToList<Supplier>();
```

But I can't make this work; please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to chain your LINQ expressions, like this:

```
var filteredList = unfilteredData
    .Where(f => f.Active == false && f.FieldId == SupplierFieldID)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.ModifiedDatetime)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

You do not need a `ToList()`, because you need a single item, not a list; this is what `FirstOrDefault()` does. If you need the last item, you need to order by the reverse of your original ordering condition. For example, if you would like the entry with the latest modified date, you need to order by descending (as you did).

Comment: You can pass the lambda into the call to FirstOrDefault and get rid of the Where here.

`unfilteredData.OrderByDescending(m => m.ModifiedDatetime).FirstOrDefault(f => f.Active == false && f.FieldId == SupplierFieldID);`

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Right, except in this case the entire list would need to be ordered. Assuming that filtering significantly reduces the number of entries, a separate `Where` may be desirable for performance reasons.

Comment: I'd consider that premature optimzation, personally, and would prefer a single selector with the filter condition for readability, but my comment is a nit pick at any rate.

Comment: Hi dasblinkenlight, thanks a lot for your kindness. If I would like to use your code in a function, what kind of data type I should use to return the result?

Comment: I'm still new in StackOverflow, thanks for sharing the info :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one statement, chaining together the LINQ operators:

```
var filteredList = myList.Where(f => f.Active == false && f.FieldId == SupplierFieldID)
                         .OrderByDescending(m => m.ModifiedDatetime)
                         .Take(1);
```

or as @Preston Guillot suggested, the even shorter form:

```
var filteredList = unfilteredData
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.ModifiedDatetime)
            .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Active == false && f.FieldId == SupplierFieldID);
```

Comment: Hi Mitch, thanks a lot for your kindness. If I would like to use your code in a function, what kind of data type I should use to return the result?

Comment: whatever you list data type is

Comment: Thanks a lot Mitch. I'm still new and need more time to get use to Lambda Expression... :)